# How does this string reverse recursion work?

Tags: c, recursion

I usually understand recursions pretty well, but because I'm new to C functions like `strcpy` and pointers I couldn't figure out how this recursion reverses a string:

```
char *reverse(char *string)
{
    if (strlen(string) <= 1)
        return string;

    else
    {
        char temp = *string;

        strcpy(string, reverse(string+1));

        *(string+strlen(string)) = temp;

        return string;
    }
}
```

The `strcpy` part seems a little bit complicated to me, and also what's the purpose of this line:
`*(string+strlen(string)) = temp;`?

I realize that after flipping the string you need to add the character that was at the beginning to the end of the string, but I'm not sure I understand the logic behind this code.

Comment: The strcpy() is dangerous here, since destination and source can overlap. Memmove() would be appropriate. (but harder to get right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is extremely inefficient but what it does is:

1. Save the original first character
2. Recursively reverse the rest of the string (`string+1` is a pointer to the second character in the string).
3. Copy the rest of the (reversed) string one character to the left.
4. Put the original first character at the end (`*(string+strlen(string)) = temp;`).

The `*(string+strlen(string)) = temp;` is equivalent to `string[strlen(string)] = temp;` if that is easier to understand.

I will not recommend using this code at all, since it is extremely inefficient -- it copies the entire string (and measures its length twice) in every iteration, not to mention waste stack space.

A much better implementation would be:

```
void reverse(char *s) {
  char *e = s+strlen(s)-1;
  while (e > s) {
    char tmp = *s;
    *s=*e;
    *e=tmp;
    s++; e--:
  }
}
```

Comment: But if I send a pointer to "ABC", then after `string` points to "BC", it is changed to CC - `string+strlen(string)` points to the zero terminator, isn't it? shouldn't it be `string+strlen(string)-1`?

Comment: Yes, except the `strcpy` also copied the null terminator, moving it one place back, shortening the string. Again, very dangerous and inefficient.

Comment: Thank you for your help; the implementation you added makes much more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

`*(string+strlen(string)) = temp` is so-called *pointer arithmetic* - that code is equivalent to `string[strlen(string)] = temp`. Therefore, this puts the **temp** character to the end of the string. Note that the string still remains zero-terminated as reverse() returns string of the same length as its argument.

The `reverse(string+1)` is again pointer arithmetic, this time same as `reverse(&string[1])` - i.e., **reverse()** will mirror the string *from the second character onwards*, but then **strcpy()** will place it at the beginning of the string, overwriting the first character that is stored in **temp** and put at the end of the string.

However, the overall code looks needlessly convoluted and inefficient, so I'd think twice before drawing any lessons on how to do things from it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's surprising me because it's an exercise from a C programming book written by someone from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the code works. The input string is divided in two parts,
the first character, and the rest. The first character is stored in `temp`,
and the rest is reversed through a recursive call. The result of the recursive call is placed at the beginning of the result, and the character in `temp` is placed at the end.

`string is [1234567890]`

`temp is 1, string+1 is [234567890]`

`reverse(string+1) is [098765432], temp is 1`

the `strcopy` line is the part that copies the result from `reverse(string+1)` at the beginning of `string`, and `*(string+strlen(string)) = temp` is the part that copies `temp` at the end of `string`.